# Error in R "Don't know how to get path data from object of class character"

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to build a leaflet map in R markdown. But I get the error mentioned in the title. Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Types of buildings in Luxembourg"
author: "Elide Nicotra"
date: '2022-05-19'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
```

## R Markdown file
## Points map

```{r}
lux_lng <- 6.1319
lux_lat <- 49.6116

points_lng <- lux_lng + rnorm(26)/10
points_lat <- lux_lat + rnorm(26)/10
popup_content <- sample(LETTERS, 26)

leaflet(width='100%') %>% 
  setView(lng=lux_lng,lat=lux_lat, zoom=9) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=points_lng, lat=points_lat, popup=popup_content)
```

## GeoJSON and loading data 

```{r}
Buildings <- rgdal::readOGR("BuildingsLux.geojson", verbose = FALSE)
data <- data.frame(Buildings@data)
```

Error: unexpected ',' in "Schools <- (data$name == "schools","


## Unique names and types of buildings 
```{r}
Names <- unique(data$name)
Types <- unique(data$type)
```

## Categorical classification 
```{r}
catpal <- colorFactor(topo.colors(length(Types)), Types)
Buildingscol <- catpal(data$type)
```


## continuous classification
## Buildingscol <- contpal(as.integer(as.factor(NullApartment$name)))

```{r}
leaflet(data = Types , width='100%') %>% 
  setView(lng=points_lng, lat=points_lat, zoom=9) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(color=Buildingscol, popup = data$type) %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomright", labels=Types, col = catpal(Types))
```
````

Error in polygonData.default(data) :
Don't know how to get path data from object of class character

Does anyone see the problem please?

Comment: I am having the same problem, were you able solve it?

Comment: You're specifying `leaflet(data = Types`, i.e., you've passing in your vector `Types` as the data object to Leaflet. Whereas leaflet expects spatial data. Perhaps you meant `leaflet(data = Buildings` ?